# LinkedList code in python

Tags: python

```
__author__ = 'jarvis'
class Node:
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.next = None
        self.data = num

class LList:
    def __init__(self, h=None):
        self.head = None

    def insert_node(self, num):
        node = Node(num)
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = node
        else:
            node.next = self.head
            self.head = node

    def print_list(self):
        node = self.head
        while not (node is None):
            print node.data
            node = node.next

lis = LList()
lis.insert_node(10)
lis.insert_node(20)
lis.insert_node(30)
lis.print_list()
```

I am very new to Python. I am trying to create a LinkedList. No error is shown but nothing is getting displayed. When I am trying to debug. The program is exiting without anything happening. Not able to understand what the problem is.

Comment: I was able to get this program to work. How are you running the program?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be setting node.next = self.head. You should be maintaining a pointer to both the head and tail. I've modified your code below.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.next = None
        self.data = num

class LList:
    def __init__(self, h=None):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None

    def insert_node(self, num):
        node = Node(num)
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = node
            self.tail = self.head
        else:
            self.tail.next= node
            self.tail = node

    def print_list(self):
        node = self.head
        while not (node is None):
            print node.data
            node = node.next
```

Comment: The existing code is simply inserting the node to the front of the list. It works fine.

Comment: I guess if he wants a Stack. not a LinkedList :) But sure

Comment: Still nothing is getting printed. And why do I need to maintain another tail pointer. `node.next = self.head`, is this statement invalid.

Comment: So it depends on what you're trying to do. Do you want a list that maintains elements in a FIFO or LIFO order? Your implementation adds elements to the front of the list which is a Stack. Putting that aside though, how are you running the code? I have tested the code and it works fine.

Comment: I am using LIFO to maintain elements. I am using Pycharm to execute my code. There are no errors shown while i am running the code. But in my code I am executing the function `print_list`, which should print the list. But when I am executing the code the list is not getting printed.

Comment: Try running the code using the python CLI tool. It sounds like a problem with your IDE, not the code.